# How to fetch percentage wise data from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a below-mentioned table:

Table1:

```
ID      Type     Date
A-1     Low      2019-01-01 13:15:19
A-2     Medium   2019-01-02 13:15:19
A-3     High     2019-01-03 13:15:19
A-4     High     2019-01-04 13:15:19
A-5     High     2019-01-05 13:15:19
A-6     Low      2019-01-06 13:15:19
A-7     Low      2019-01-07 13:15:19
A-8     Low      2019-01-08 13:15:19
A-9     Medium   2019-01-09 13:15:19
A-10    Medium   2019-01-10 13:15:19
A-11    Low      2019-02-01 13:15:19
A-12    Medium   2019-02-02 13:15:19
A-13    Low      2019-02-03 13:15:19
A-14    Low      2019-02-04 13:15:19
A-15    Low      2019-02-05 13:15:19
A-16    Low      2019-02-06 13:15:19
A-17    Low      2019-02-07 13:15:19
A-18    Low      2019-02-08 13:15:19
A-19    Medium   2019-02-09 13:15:19
A-20    Medium   2019-02-10 13:15:19
```

How can I fetch the percentage-wise date based on the `Type` for Month, For Example, 10% of `Type` Low and 20% of `Type` Medium and 10% of `Type` High for all total number of `ID` for a particular Month.

Also, If for a particular month if the `Type` is not available, take the same percentage of `ID` from `Type` Low. (as explained in the required output)

Required Output

```
Month     Type    ID 
Jan-19    Low     A-1
Jan-19    Medium  A-2
Jan-19    Medium  A-9
Jan-19    High    A-3
Feb-19    Low     A-11
Feb-19    Medium  A-12
Feb-19    Medium  A-19
Feb-19    Low     A-13
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I'm not calculating the percentage, I'm trying to fetch the data in percentage manner.

Comment: I don't see you trying anything here but I will remove the duplicate link.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I have tried using case when but it didn't work as expected.